# How should I limit a table to N rows, discarding oldest?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, trigger

I have a SQL Server table which I use to store events.

I only want the table to contain the 1000 most recently added rows, when row 1001 is inserted, row 1 should be deleted.

I have both a DateCreatedUTC column and an autonumber column.... I could write a query to execute a delete and trigger it on `INSERT` but I don't know that this is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: Just a thought, but what's wrong with a view on the original data? Paul...

Comment: Does it have to be 1000 rows exactly, every second of the day? Or can it be a little over 1000 rows and cleaned up periodically?

Comment: @AaronBertrand it can be cleaned periodically.

Comment: OK, updated my answer

Comment: @Verace Imagine that I have many of these tables and they get a row added every few seconds.

Comment: You could also consider presizing the table with 1000 rows then just performing updates [as a circular buffer](http://kejser.org/databases/implementing-message-queues-in-relational-databases/)

Comment: @MartinSmith Please convert you comment to an answer. While Aaron's solution is sufficient in my use case I think your suggestion is actually more fitting the "spirit" of my quesion.

Comment: If I was to make it an answer I'd need to expand it. As (a) I'm on vacation (b) I'm on a mobile device. I'll pass on that!

Comment: @MartinSmith and I'd goad you more if I, too, weren't on vacation!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a view to hide the rest of the rows when they do exist:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Top1000Rows
AS
  SELECT TOP (1000) ...columns...
    FROM dbo.table_name
    ORDER BY DateCreatedUTC DESC;
GO
```

Then periodically run this in a background job (just play with the frequency until you're happy with how often the table itself is "off", and by how much):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT pk_column, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateCreatedUTC DESC)
  FROM dbo.table_name
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1000;
```

If it doesn't have to be exactly 1,000 rows all of the time, then you can potentially forget about the view altogether, knowing that sometimes there will be more than 1,000 rows.

Comment: Good answer, will accept. I guess I was hoping there was some fixed table property to limit the number of rows in this FIFO manner... I guess not!

Comment: @Matthew No, there is nothing built in for that, seems a peculiar requirement. I am not sure exactly how SQL Server Agent history implements FIFO, but for user data I am not sure it is a common use case.